# Advantages vs Disadvantages: bool value in the parameter list to indicate async or not in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Here is a generic method for retrieval from an Azure Storage table ([examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet) in the official doc).

```
    public async Task<T> RetrieveOne<T>(string partitionKey, string rowKey, bool isAsync = false) where T : TableEntity
    {
        // To construct the query operation
        TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);

        // To execute the query
        TableResult result;
        if (isAsync)
        {
            result = await _table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
        }
        else
        {
            result = _table.Execute(retrieveOperation);
        }

        // To parse the result
        if (result.Result != null)
        {
            return (T)result.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("The result retrieved is null");
        }
    }
```

I am using `isAsync` in the parameter list to indicate whether this method is asynchronous or not. Did I make it? 
The advantages are obvious: one can easily switch options between `async` or not. 
It seems that such a style would wrap the synchronous one(`isAsync = false`) into a `Task` as well, at the price of extra cost, since kicking out tasks alone costs time as well. Any other disadvantage?

Comment: Do you observe such things in the NET framework?  Or do you see things like `LoadData()` and `LoadDataAsync`?

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 I just edited my question. Please refer to the examples added for your reference.

Comment: disadvantage in `async = false` you will not be able to use the result since it is not going to wait for execution.

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid this.. In short,

- There should be very little real-world uses-cases that would warrant it
- It could cause deadlocks
- It encourages you not use the `await` and propagate
- It adds more branching in your method
- It adds more complexity when testing
- It generally smells bad. (IMO)
- Added by [FCin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6485082/fcin), It will also generate AsyncStateMachine even if all calls are sync

Note : even writing `async` and synchronous alternatives of the same method is fairly suspicious, its harder to maintain and maybe pointing to other design issues.

If you really want to wait for an `async` method, let the caller do it, this at least give them the option to wrap it if needed or otherwise handle it appropriately

Comment: It will also generate AsyncStateMachine even if all calls are sync